# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: app.storage is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app in Angular, Ionic and I want it to send some data to firebase and display them later in my app. My problem appear when I run modal with inputs and I receive this error in my browser.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: app.storage is not a function
TypeError: app.storage is not a function
    at angular-fire-compat-storage.js:107:62
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.mjs:10877:28)
    at angular-fire-compat-storage.js:107:34
    at ɵcacheInstance (angular-fire-compat.js:147:29)
    at new AngularFireStorage (angular-fire-compat-storage.js:106:38)
    at Object.AngularFireStorage_Factory [as factory] (angular-fire-compat-storage.js:133:24)
    at core.mjs:9412:43
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:694:9)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
    at zone.js:1100:17
    at zone.js:1116:33
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:6:1)
    at _throw (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:10981:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:367:52)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
    at zone.js:1257:36
handleError @ core.mjs:11458
next @ core.mjs:28224
next @ Subscriber.js:91
_next @ Subscriber.js:60
next @ Subscriber.js:31
(anonymous) @ Subject.js:34
errorContext @ errorContext.js:19
next @ Subject.js:27
emit @ core.mjs:10568
(anonymous) @ core.mjs:11007
invoke @ zone.js:368
run @ zone.js:129
runOutsideAngular @ core.mjs:10877
onHandleError @ core.mjs:11007
handleError @ zone.js:372
runGuarded @ zone.js:142
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:1054
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:588
Promise.then (async)
nativeScheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:557
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:568
scheduleTask @ zone.js:392
scheduleTask @ zone.js:216
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:236
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:1247
resolvePromise @ zone.js:1184
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1100
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1116
postUpdateComponent @ index-847f2fde.js:1858
postUpdate @ index-847f2fde.js:1771
(anonymous) @ index-847f2fde.js:1773
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:1411
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19
updateComponent @ index-847f2fde.js:1781
(anonymous) @ index-847f2fde.js:1706
enqueue @ index-847f2fde.js:1724
dispatchHooks @ index-847f2fde.js:1706
dispatch @ index-847f2fde.js:1656
consume @ index-847f2fde.js:2515
flush @ index-847f2fde.js:2530
requestAnimationFrame (async)
raf @ ionic-angular.mjs:17
(anonymous) @ index-847f2fde.js:2508
scheduleUpdate @ index-847f2fde.js:1657
schedule @ index-847f2fde.js:2129
(anonymous) @ index-847f2fde.js:2140
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
invoke @ zone.js:368
run @ zone.js:129
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1257
invokeTask @ zone.js:402
runTask @ zone.js:173
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:581
Promise.then (async)
nativeScheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:557
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:568
scheduleTask @ zone.js:392
scheduleTask @ zone.js:216
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:236
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:1247
resolvePromise @ zone.js:1184
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1100
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1116
webpackJsonpCallback @ jsonp chunk loading:77
(anonymous) @ node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-modal_entry_js.js:2
Show 65 more frames
Show less
core.mjs:11458 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for AdService. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for AdService. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
    at throwCyclicDependencyError (core.mjs:228:11)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:9406:13)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9281:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9292:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:13939:37)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:4484:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:4532:12)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:11732:19)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.CreateAdComponent_Factory [as factory] (create-ad.component.ts:10:31)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:4738:44)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
    at zone.js:1100:17
    at zone.js:1116:33
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:6:1)
    at _throw (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:10981:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:367:52)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
    at zone.js:1257:36
```

Here is my component.ts code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AdService } from '../../ad.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-ad',
  templateUrl: 'create-ad.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['create-ad.component.scss'],
})
export class CreateAdComponent {
  title: string = '';
  content: string = '';
  location: string = '';
  contactEmail: string = '';
  price!: number;
  image!: File;

  constructor(public modalController: ModalController, private adService: AdService) {}

  closeModal() {
    this.modalController.dismiss();
  }

  submitAd() {

    this.adService.addAd(this.title, this.content, this.location, this.contactEmail, this.price, this.image);


    this.closeModal();
  }
}
```

I would like to make this thing work properly and send data to firebase because I want to display it in my app